# Copy Part of Frame in 2D Animation Mode

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

Maybe this is an obvious feature, but I am an absolute noob at Blender 2.82a's 2D animation feature and would like to know if we can copy a part of one frame and paste it to the next. For example, I want to animate a vase falling down and I want to do it the traditional frame by frame way. So can I copy the strokes from frame N and paste it to frame N+2?

I've googled it but couldn't find an option like this.

Comment: With the keyframe highlighted in the Dope Sheet (I refer here to the Dope Sheet as it specifically appears in the 2D Animation workspace), it turns out that the Shift+D shortcut works to duplicate the grease pencil keyframe (Shift+D is a standard shortcut for achieving this same "duplicate" function in other animation editors, and indeed in other non-animation related contexts as well). This keyframe can then be dragged through the timeline to a new position, and will bring all the relevant content from the copied keyframe with it.

Comment: @R-800 I'll check it out. But is there a way to select and copy some part of a frame and paste it to the next?

Comment: There are no parts of a frame. There are only frames. I think what you mean is, part of the contents of a frame. But the contents of a frame, in this case, are grease pencil objects. Understand that Blender treats your drawn strokes as belonging to either one or another grease pencil object. It wouldn't be a straightforward matter to take part of the contents one of these grease pencil objects and leave other parts. I don't know if it's possible to do something like that. It's understandable that this would be wanted, though. Copying and pasting strokes is straightforward in 2D art programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy part/s of a Grease Pencil object (Strokes and Points) as follows:

### Copy/Paste

1. Go to the source Frame in the timeline
2. Ensure Blender is in Object Mode
3. Select your Grease Pencil Object
4. Change Blender to Edit Mode
5. Select the desired strokes/points/parts of the Object
6. Copy with: **Ctrl-C**  -or-  right-click Copy  -or-  [Grease Pencil] > Copy
7. Change to the destination Frame in the timeline (new or existing)
8. Paste with: **Ctrl-V**  -or-  right-click Paste  -or-  [Grease Pencil] > Paste
9. *optionally* Return to Object Mode (or continue editing)

You can also use similar techniques to copy parts of one Grease Pencil Object into another.

### Duplicate

For Steps 5,6,7,8 - you can also use Duplicate (Shift-D) as follows:

5. Select the desired strokes/points/parts of the Object
6. Change to the destination Frame in the timeline (new or existing)
7. Duplicate with: **Shift-D**  -or-  right-click Duplicate -or-  [Grease Pencil] > Duplicate
8. Hit [Enter] or left-click in the workspace to position the new duplicate

The Duplicate method has the effect of merging the Strokes and Points into whatever is currently visible in the destination frame.